# Wilcard ssh config does not match anymore

Tags: ssh

I had this ssh config:

```
Host git.domain.net
    Port 22

Host *.domain.net
    Port 2121

Host bastion
    HostName nx4201.domain.net
    User dummy

Host project_production
    HostName nx4242.domain.net
    User project
```

I was on Ubuntu 15.10 and doing `ssh project_production` was working, connecting on nx4242.domain.net with port 2121.

I'm now on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and I reimported the same config file (it's versionning under a private git repository).

This is not working anymore:

```
$ ssh -vvv project_production 
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/sullivan/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/sullivan/.ssh/config line 12: Applying options for project_production
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "nx4242.domain.net" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to nx4242.domain.net [178.170.104.70] port 22.
```

As you can see, ssh now tries to connect with port `22` and doesn't care about the `*.domain.net` rule.

I know I can specify the port on each host but I have a lot of them.

Why is this not working now but working on the old system? How to fix it?

FYI, here is the system ssh config file:

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

The SSH version:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Comment: Incidentally, underscore characters are not legal in hostnames per [RFC 952](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc952).  That might be related to why you ran into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1024928/650657

In a nutshell I have to add this line:

```
CanonicalizeHostname yes
Host *.mydomain.com
    User myusername

Host host1
    HostName host1.mydomain.com
```

With this, the config file will be re-parsed.

The strange thing is I didn't have to use the `CanonicalizeHostname` option before...